# How to add a custom SurfaceView to a FrameLayout in a FragmentView

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, surfaceview, android-framelayout

I have a view that has a FrameLayout in which I dynamically place a custom SurfaceView class. In other regular Activities, I am able to do this without a problem. Attempting to do the same thing in a Fragment causes an issue. When I try to add the SurfaceView to the FrameLayout, only black appears. This has also happened when trying to dynamically place it into the FrameLayout of a ListView, which also used a LayoutInflater. I believe the problem lies there, but I can not figure out how to fix this.

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
    .inflate(R.layout.view_the_graph, container);

// Add the graph to the view
GraphView = new GraphSurfaceView(getActivity(), false);
frame = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutDisplay);
frame.addView(GrapView);
```